# React router 4 custom component giving render function error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import React,{Component,} from 'react';
import {Route,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class PrivateRoute extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
    render(){
        const {component, authed, ...rest}=this.props;
        return(
            <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => authed === true
              ? <Component {...this.props} />
              : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />} />
        )
    }
}
```

Error:ReactComponent(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`.

Comment: Does your component look exactly the same of there are some things in the constructor as well

Comment: `<Component {...this.props} />` is not a valid `component` you need to create a new component class with a render method and put that there instead.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `Component` as a output in your render method you need to create classes that extend it.:

**Create TestComponent**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <span>Hello</span>
    }
}
```

**PrivateRoute**

Please note that I have removed the `constructor` as it is not needed here:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import TestComponent from './TestComponent';

export default class PrivateRoute extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const {component, authed, ...rest}=this.props;
        return(
            <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => authed === true
              ? <TestComponent {...this.props} />
              : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />} />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: @VivekMalik Please click the tick and upvote this answer so that others know that it has been resolved.